# Azure Portal gives error when trying to change SendGrid account password

Tags: azure, sendgrid, change-password

In Azure, I am trying to change my password for a SendGrid account.  I navigate to the Change Password blade and carefully enter in my current password and the new password (twice).  All fields have green ticks against them.  However, when I choose "Save", the field "Re-enter password" gets blanked out and a red error shows up - "The value should not be empty".  I have tried in IE, Firefox and Chrome browsers - all give same error.
Any suggestions?
I cannot change the password in SendGrid as the fields are greyed out - I guess I am meant to use the Azure portal.

Comment: All fixed now - Yay!  Goo Microsoft!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed now - Yay! Go Microsoft!